# npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.start odas_studio

Tags: node.js, npm, build, raspberry-pi, node-modules

The following is my error message:

```
google@raspberrypi:~/Desktop/odas_web $ npm start

> odas_studio@0.3.0 start /home/google/Desktop/odas_web
> electron .


(electron:35503): Gtk-WARNING **: 23:03:25.467: cannot open display:
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! odas_studio@0.3.0 start: `electron .`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the odas_studio@0.3.0 start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/google/.npm/_logs/2023-07-29T15_03_25_554Z-debug.log
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rv9hk.png)

I am using ReSpeaker_4_Mic_Array on Raspberry Pi, following the tutorial at https://wiki.seeedstudio.com/ReSpeaker_4_Mic_Array_for_Raspberry_Pi/#record-sound-with-python.
To start ODAS Studio, I run npm start, but I receive an error.

I have tried the following commands:

```
rm -rf node_modules 
rm package-lock.json yarn.lock 
npm cache clear --force
npm install
```

or

```
npm update
```

and

```
npm install webpack --save
```

but I still encounter the error.

This is my error log:

```
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [ '/usr/bin/node', '/usr/bin/npm', 'start' ]
2 info using npm@6.14.16
3 info using node@v12.22.12
4 verbose run-script [ 'prestart', 'start', 'poststart' ]
5 info lifecycle odas_studio@0.3.0~prestart: odas_studio@0.3.0
6 info lifecycle odas_studio@0.3.0~start: odas_studio@0.3.0
7 verbose lifecycle odas_studio@0.3.0~start: unsafe-perm in lifecycle true
8 verbose lifecycle odas_studio@0.3.0~start: PATH: /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-lifecycle/node-gyp-bin:/h>9 verbose lifecycle odas_studio@0.3.0~start: CWD: /home/google/Desktop/odas_web
10 silly lifecycle odas_studio@0.3.0~start: Args: [ '-c', 'electron .' ]
11 silly lifecycle odas_studio@0.3.0~start: Returned: code: 1  signal: null
12 info lifecycle odas_studio@0.3.0~start: Failed to exec start script
13 verbose stack Error: odas_studio@0.3.0 start: `electron .`
13 verbose stack Exit status 1
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.<anonymous> (/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-lifecycle/index.js:332:16)
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:314:20)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-lifecycle/lib/spawn.js:55:>13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:314:20)
13 verbose stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:1022:16)
13 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:287:5)
14 verbose pkgid odas_studio@0.3.0
15 verbose cwd /home/google/Desktop/odas_web
16 verbose Linux 6.1.21-v8+
```

Please help me!

Comment: The log is literally telling you the problem isn't with `npm`, so... read the log it's telling you lives at `/home/google/.npm/_logs/2023-07-29T15_03_25_554Z-debug.log` and see what _is_ the problem? Did you already search for `Failed at the odas_studio@0.3.0 start script` to see if anyone else had _that_ error? Because if I search for that, I immediately find things like https://github.com/introlab/odas_web/issues/53

Comment: Of course, I have already searched to see if others have similar issues. I have also tried the solutions provided in the link you shared, but they did not work for me.

Comment: But then [why was that not in your post](/help/how-to-ask)? Remember to include all the details of your problem _including_ all the (re)searching and debugging you already did. That said, did you file a new issue on the odas issue tracker? Because that's the _first_ place to post, even if you then follow up by posting to Stackoverflow (which is your _last_ resort when there are no other, better places to get help)